In jupyter, how do I filter the whole output function?
Is there a way to filter what is given in the output from a Jupyter cell? I.e. modify the whole print function? I want the output of a request to be filtered of an API key, so it is not spread by accident.
Example of url that is generated, and printed in cell after using the python library I cannot modify:

websiteWhereIWantToUseApi.com/API/?authKey=APIKEYHERE&maxYearCount=33...

I want to share my repository with Jupyter notebooks with others, and have set up filter so you don't commit modified jupyter notebooks, but the library I import does print the URL with the API key.
So, ofc I can put ; on each line, I can use %%capture to change output, but still when creating a new cell I might forget to add it and my friends will do this misstake I am sure.
How do I make sure that neither I or my friends will print API keys in our notebook and publish it by misstake?

I think you can use this answer overload print python. with a small addition you should be able to change the functionality of the print function, and hide undesired output. (Provided that your library uses print(...) to output stuff.

Some more Jupyter-centric ideas: If ; would do it in this case (it usually only suppresses what the last line would return) then you could make a custom magic that uses input transformation to add it everytime behind-the-scenes. I don't even know if you need the custom magic. As for targeting the output, see my answer here where I have an example defining a custom format handler and links to other useful resources along this line. And you might want to wrap use of this API in a custom magic so that they'd have to run some code at the top to ...

 even use your notebooks. And in that custom magic defining cell, you can wrap in the custom handler. This way if they start the kernel up later and try to run cells, they won't bypass your handler. Of course, you'll have to stress to them whenever they see that magic line and get it not define, it means to run the top cell you put at the start of the notebook.

Thank you for the pointers, I will have a look at them and see if I can solve it this way.
